# Ruby Code Translation Request

Tags: ruby, pseudocode

I have negligible Ruby syntax knowledge and was hoping someone would be kind enough to translate the function below into pseudo code and possibly provide an example of how it would be called?

```
def in_list(num, list) 
   list = [*list] 
   list.each {|a,b| return (b)? num.sub(a,b) : a if num =~ a} 
   nil 
end
```

Comment: Any idea what arguments this code is called with?  I've had a crack at understanding it but I'm pretty confused.  It's either too clever or too stupid for me to understand the original intention.

Comment: it's too stupid.  Good code is commented, uses meaningful variable names, and is, in many ways, not this piece of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wow.  That's some ugly ruby.

So `num` here is actually a `String` (the tip offs being the use of the `#sub` and `#=~` methods.

`list` is an `Array` of

- `Regexp` objects and/or
- pairs of `Regexp` and replacement `String` objects.

If none of the given `Regexp`s match the string, the method returns `nil`.

If an unpaired `Regexp` matches the string, the method returns that `Regexp`.

If a paired `Regexp` matches the string, the method substitutes the part of the string
that the `Regexp` matches with the paired replacement text, and returns the modified `String`.

Once a `Regexp` matches the string, the method returns - no later `Regexp`s are considered.

In no cases is the original `String` modified.

It's really a franken-method, IMHO, since it's trying to do very different things.

An example call:

```
 in_list("abe lincoln", [ [/linc/, 'zelda'] ]) #=> "abe zeldaoln"
 in_list("abe lincoln", [ [/linc/] ]) #=> /linc/
 in_list("abe lincoln", [ [/link/] ]) #=> nil
```

Really, with that multitude of return types, it seems like more of a pain in the ass than it's worth.

In pseudo-code

```
  DEF IN-LIST( text, regexps )
    FOREACH regexp IN regexps
      IF HAS-MATCH( text, regexp )
        IF HAS-REPLACEMENT-TEXT( regexp )
          RETURN REPLACE-MATCHED-PORTION( text, regexp, GET-REPLACEMENT-TEXT(regexp) )
        ELSE
          RETURN regexp
        ENDIF
      ENDIF
    ENDFOREACH
    RETURN NOTHING-FOUND
  ENDDEF
```

But like I said, this is some ugly-ass ruby.  I'd avoid using it.  It's a codesmell that tells me there's a whole lot wrong with this code.

If I had an array of `Regexps`, and wanted to find the first one that matched some text, I'd do:

```
# general case
regexps.find { |re| text =~ re }
# example
[ /earn/, /more/, /sessions/, /by/, /sleaving/ ].find { |re| "A baby?" =~ re } # would return /by/
```

If I had an collection of `Regexp`, replacement text pairs, and I wanted to replace the first match in some text, I'd do this

```
# general case
text_dupe = text.dup
pairs.find { |re,replace| text_dupe.sub!( re, replace ) }
# example
text_dupe = "One two three four".dup
[ [/ape/, 'frog'], [/our/, 'my'] ].find { |re,replace| text_dupe.sub!( re, replace } } # would return "One two three fmy"
```

I'd rather use a `Hash` for the last actually, but since that loses the order the original list came in (and who am I to say
that's not important, not knowing how it's used), I didn't.

Comment: Was halfway through writing an answer when you posted yours.  I'd come to the same conclusions re: regexp matching, and agree it is ugly as anything.